# Error- no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>' and 'char')

Tags: c++

I'm new to StackOverflow, and coding in general. I'm getting this error whenever I try to run my program:

> [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>' and 'char')

It's because of a function I made to check if the filename, which consists of their full name and student ID that they previously entered, is correct and the same with the filename they are making. So basically:

```
Name: Lucius
Student ID: 12345678910
```

In the file name section, they enter:

```
File name: Lucius - 12345678910
```

It would check if it's the same or not.

This is the function:

```cpp
void filenamechecking(char studentname, char separatorchecking, int idnumber);


void filenamechecking (char studentname, char separatorchecking, int idnumber){
    
    const char dashchecking = '-' ;
    
    char filename;
    int filestudentid; 
    
    if (cin >> filename == studentname && 
        cin >> separatorchecking && separatorchecking == dashchecking &&
        cin >> filestudentid == idnumber) 
    {
        cout << "\n You have entered the appropriate file name" << endl;
    }
    else cout << "\n INVALID FILE NAME" << endl;  
}
```

This is where I'm invoking it:

```cpp
cout << "File Name (Student Name - Student Number): ";
filenamechecking (fullname, separatorinput, studentid);
cout << "\n";
                 
cin.sync();
```

Comment: WRONG: `char filename ... cin >> filename == studentname`.  BETTER: `std:string filename...`

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on the proposed answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Here, in `cin >> filename == studentname` the return of the `cin >> filename` will be reference to `cin`. Thus, you compare `std::cin` and `studentname`, hence no match for the operator `==`.

You should also reconsider the [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of operators you use in the condition.

It will be correct and much more readable to do like so:

```
if (cin >> filename && cin >> separatorchecking && cin >> filestudentid) // If input is valid
    if (filename == studentname && separatorchecking == dashchecking && filestudentid == idnumber)
        /* do processing */;
```

*Also, you should consider using `std::string`. Since a `char` type for a name of a file or a student is a questionable choice.*